# Cartesian product and closure

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$. Show that in the space $X \times Y$, $$\overline{A \times B}= \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$$

$\subset$: let $x \in \overline{A \times B}$.

Then for every open set $W$ containing $x$, $W \cap (A\times B) \neq \emptyset$

Since $W$ is an open set of $X \times Y$, $W= U \times V$ such that $U$ is an open set in $X$ and $V$ is an open set in $Y$.

We have: $W \cap (A \times B)\neq \emptyset \iff (U \times V) \cap (A\times B) \neq \emptyset \iff (U \cap A) \times (V \cap B) \neq \emptyset \iff U\cap A \neq\emptyset \text{ or } V \cap B\neq \emptyset$

Since $x \in W= U \times V$, $x= (u,v)$ such that $u \in U$ and $v \in V$

$\bullet$ There exists an open set $U$in $X$ containing $u$ such that $U \cap A= \emptyset$

Therefore $u \in \overline{A}$

$\bullet$ Similarly $v \in \overline{B}$

Since $x= (u,v) \in U \times V, x\in \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$

Hence: $\overline{A \times B} \subset \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$

$\supset$: Conversly, let $x \in \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$

$x=(a,b) \in \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$ such that $a\in \overline{A}$ and $b\in \overline{B}$

$\bullet$ There is an open set $U$ in $X$ containing $a$ such that $U \cap A\neq \emptyset$

$\bullet$ There is an open set $V$ in $Y$ containing $b$ such that $V \cap B\neq \emptyset$

Therefore $U \times V$ is an open set in $X \times Y$ containing $x=(a,b)$ such that $(U\times V) \cap (A\times B)\neq \emptyset \Rightarrow x\in \overline{A \times B}$

$\overline{A} \times \overline{B} \subset \overline{A \times B}$

Hence: $\overline{A \times B}= \overline{A} \times \overline{B}$

Comment: You are quite lost. For instance: it should not be $W\cap\left(A\times B\right)=\emptyset$ but $W\cap A\times B\neq\emptyset$. If there is an open $U$ containing $a$ with $U\cap A$ empty then $a$ does *not* belong to the closure of $A$. If you want an answer then first you have some repairing to do.

Comment: @drhab Yes I just realised that. I'm really sorry about that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A shorter route for one of the parts:

$A\times B\subset\overline{A}\times\overline{B}$ and $\overline{A}\times\overline{B}=\left(\overline{A}\times Y\right)\cap\left(X\times\overline{B}\right)$
is - as intersection of closed sets - closed in the producttopology.
Then $\overline{A\times B}\subset\overline{A}\times\overline{B}$.

**addendum**

The other part:

Let $\left(a,b\right)\in\overline{A}\times\overline{B}$ and let $W$
be open in $X\times Y$ with $\left(a,b\right)\in W$. Then some $U$ open
in $X$ and some $V$ open in $Y$ will exist with $\left(a,b\right)\in U\times V\subset W$.
Then $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$ and $V\cap B\neq\emptyset$. Let $x\in U\cap A$
and let $y\in V\cap B$. Then $\left(x,y\right)\in W\cap\left(A\times B\right)$.
This proves that every open set that contains $\left(a,b\right)$
has a non-empty intersection with $A\times B$. So $\left(a,b\right)\in\overline{A\times B}$.

Comment: By what argument have we already proven that $\overline{\ \dot\ }$ respects the $\subset$? (I know that it respects by $\overline{A}=A\cup \partial A$ but at this level we don't know this fact I think.)

Comment: @C.F.G IMV this becomes clear  immediately by the definition of the closure of $A$. This e.g. as intersection of all closed subsets that contain $A$. I cannot find any definition where it is not immediately clear. So if a student is at the level of knowing $\overline A$ then he is also at the level of knowing that $A\subseteq\overline A$.

Comment: What is the relevancy of the last line to my question? ($A\subseteq\overline A$) Some books define it as this: The set of all interior points together with all of its limit points. (If I am not mistaken)

Comment: From $A\subseteq B$ it follows that $A\subseteq\overline B$ and, because  $\overline B$ is closed,  $\overline A\subset\overline B$. What you propose as definition is not correct. Let $A$ be a non-trivial subset of $X$ equipped with indiscrete topology. Then the interior of $A$ is empty hence has no limit points. But the closure of $A$ is $X$. In a correct version it is stated that the closure of $A$ is the union of $A$ and the set of its limit points, making clear immediately that $A$ is a subset of its closure.

Comment: Thanks for correction. My question is this: if $B\subset \overline{A}$ then  how $B\cup \lim B\subset \overline{A}\cup\lim B$ implies  $\overline{B}\subset \overline{A}$? i.e. $B\subset A\implies\lim B\subset \lim A$?

Comment: @C.F.G If $x$ is a limit point of $B$ then by definition of limitpoint every open set containing $x$ will contain some $y\in B$ with $x\neq y$. If $B\subseteq A$ then also $y\in A$ hence we find that $x$ is also a limitpoint of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof for $\supseteq$ is correct, but your proof for $\subseteq$ isn't quite. You said

> Since $W$ is an open set of $X \times Y$, $W= U \times V$ such that $U$ is an open set in $X$ and $V$ is an open set in $Y$.

This isn't true, since sets of the form $U \times V$ for $U \subseteq X$ and $V \subseteq Y$ open don't form a topology on $X \times Y$; but they do *generate* a topology. In other words, any open $W \ni x$ can be written as a union of sets of the form $U \times V$. This means that we can say $x \in U \times V$ for some $U$ open in $X$ and $V$ open in $Y$, such that $(U \times V) \cap (A \times B) \ne \varnothing$.

Most of your other reasoning goes through fine, except most (all?) of the times where you've written $= \varnothing$ you should have written $\ne \varnothing$.

Comment: Ah! Sorry. That's unforgivable

Comment: I agree with your first comment. I actually thought that I could use the concept used with the basis of a product topology i.e. if B is a basis of a topology on X and C is a basis of a topology on Y, then the set $D= \{U \times V; U \in B, V \in C \}$ is a basis of the product topology on $X \times Y$